# mySQL query most common value. Show value and count

Tags: php, mysql

I want to query the database to show the most common 3 values in a column (TyreMan). Then display the values and the number of occurrences

```
$sqlCommand = "SELECT TyreMan, COUNT(TyreMan) AS countTyreMan 
  FROM Pictures WHERE Tyreman IS NOT NULL AND Tyreman <> 'UNKNOWN' 
  GROUP BY TyreMan ORDER BY countTyreMan ASC LIMIT 3";
$query = mysql_query($sqlCommand) or die (mysql_error()); 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
$manu = $row["TyreMan"];
echo "$manu";
```

At the moment i just get

```
value1value2value3
```

how do i get the count and display it like this?

```
value1 [count], value2 [count], value3 [count]
```

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why is the last bracket of your code missing? Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain how it's failing.

Comment: you´ve got the query right just do not have right front end code, if you do not add some html it will show everything without format...

Comment: The SQL is almost correct, except you need to sort by `COUNT(TyreMan) DESC`.  Your php code seems to be missing something.

Comment: DESC is highest to lowest, if you really want most common. And count(*) is fine - no need to call out the column; the GROUP BY is doing that. And your formatting; echo "$manu\n" - if you want them on separate lines. The cursor sits at the end of the last echo otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the count to a string and concatenate it with the value.

```
$manu = $manu . $row["TyreMan"] .  '[' . $row["countTyreMan"] . ']';
```

Comment: perfect :) thanks for interpreting my post. Sorry if i didn't provide the full code.